# Django Channels (and other framework) session id/key uses

Tags: django, django-channels, django-sessions

I would like to assign a meaningful value to `self.group_name` in a channels application and I would like this tied to the user session (i.e. data will go anywhere the same user is logged in).

Is it safe to use the session ID (from `self.scope['session'].session_key`) as this identifier, provided this value never leaves the server? I want my channels connection lifetime to match that of my Django session, so this seems like the most straight forward approach and avoids cluttering up the session with other variables.

The alternative would be to assign something like a `uuid4` value to a new session variable. That would make it more difficult for me to leak a users session_key.

Answer (score 0):

You can and it will work. With Channels 2 nothing is going to the users unless you explicitly tell it to. Each connection already has an asgi_channel though so instead of making groups for 1 user that will just send to the asgi_channel you can send to the asgi_channel directly. You would probably want to map the session key to the asgi_channel in the cache. Make sure you use sync_to_async or an async library when you work with the cache because it will block the event loop.